How to implement Tabbed Layout with Navigation Compose Deep linking
Leveraging the latest support for type safe navigtion in Compose , how can I implement deep linking in a tabbed layout UI that would look something like this:

The important bit is the content scrolls between tabs (unlike Bottom Navigation, which fades between content), like so:
https://m3.material.io/components/tabs/guidelines#a10c71e1-a038-4ff7-8e2f-1ece2a34e15c
Is there documentation or best practices here? or open source examples?

You can use Voyager library for compose.
Here is the link:
Voyager Tab Navigation

thanks! but I’m looking for the recommended approach on how to do this with compose navigation
